# KVM server on CentOS 7 bonding 2 NICs and bridging vlans networking configuration not working

Tags: networking, centos7, vlan, bridge, bonding

I am trying to setup CentOS 7 on a server to host VM's via KVM. The networking I am trying to set up should allow multiple vlans across the two NICs via bond/bridge setup. It's not working at all. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

bonding.conf

```
alias bond0 bonding
options bond0 miimon=100 mode=4 lacp_rate=1
```

bond0.conf

```
alias bond0 bonding
options bond0 miimon=100 mode=4 lacp_rate=1
```

ifcfg-lo

```
DEVICE=lo
IPADDR=127.0.0.1
NETMASK=255.0.0.0
NETWORK=127.0.0.0
BROADCAST=127.255.255.255
ONBOOT=yes
NAME=loopback
```

ifcfg-bond0

```
# Use tagged VLANs
ARP=no
BOOTPROTO=none
DEVICE=bond0
IPV6INIT=no
## Optional, use for jumbo frames if needed
#MTU=9000
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
NOZEROCONF=yes
ONBOOT=yes
BONDING_MASTER=yes
BONDING_OPTS="mode=4 miimon=100 updelay=30000"
```

ifcfg-bond0.341

```
DEVICE=bond0.341
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
VLAN=yes
BRIDGE=br341
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
```

ifcfg-bond0.342

```
DEVICE=bond0.342
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
VLAN=yes
BRIDGE=br342
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
```

ifcfg-bond0.400

```
DEVICE=bond0.400
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
VLAN=yes
BRIDGE=br400
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
```

ifcfg-bond0.450

```
DEVICE=bond0.450
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
VLAN=yes
BRIDGE=br450
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
```

ifcfg-br341

```
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
DEVICE=br341
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Bridge
VLAN=yes
# IPv4
DNS1=192.168.36.3
DNS2=192.168.100.3
DNS3=192.168.160.10
NOZEROCONF=yes
STP=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="Bridge br341"
BRIDGING_OPTS=priority=32768
IPADDR=192.168.34.21
PREFIX=26
GATEWAY=192.168.34.1
NETWORK=192.168.34.0
```

ifcfg-br342

```
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
DEVICE=br342
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Bridge
VLAN=yes
# IPv4
DNS1=192.168.36.3
DNS2=192.168.100.3
DNS3=192.168.160.10
NOZEROCONF=yes
STP=yes
BRIDGING_OPTS=priority=32768
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=192.168.34.86
GATEWAY=192.168.34.65
NETWORK=192.168.34.64
PREFIX=26
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="Bridge br342"
```

ifcfg-br400

```
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
DEVICE=br400
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Bridge
VLAN=yes
# IPv4
DNS1=192.168.36.3
DNS2=192.168.100.3
DNS3=192.168.160.10
NOZEROCONF=yes
STP=yes
BRIDGING_OPTS=priority=32768
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=192.168.43.21
GATEWAY=192.168.43.1
NETWORK=192.168.43.0
PREFIX=26
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="Bridge br400"
```

ifcfg-br450

```
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
DEVICE=br450
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Bridge
VLAN=yes
# IPv4
DNS1=192.168.36.3
DNS2=192.168.100.3
DNS3=192.168.160.10
NOZEROCONF=yes
STP=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=192.168.34.150
GATEWAY=192.168.34.129
NETWORK=192.168.34.128
PREFIX=26
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="Bridge br450"
```

ifcfg-em1

```
TYPE=Ethernet
DEVICE=em1
ONBOOT=yes
MASTER=bond0
NOZEROCONF=yes
ONBOOT=yes
SLAVE=yes
NAME="System em1"
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
```

ifcfg-em1.341

```
DEVICE=em1.341
ONBOOT=yes
VLAN=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
SLAVE=yes
MASTER=bond0.341
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
```

ifcfg-em1.342

```
DEVICE=em1.342
ONBOOT=yes
VLAN=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
SLAVE=yes
MASTER=bond0.342
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
```

ifcfg-em1.400

```
DEVICE=em1.342
ONBOOT=yes
VLAN=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
SLAVE=yes
MASTER=bond0.342
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
```

ifcfg-em1.450

```
DEVICE=em1.450
ONBOOT=yes
VLAN=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
SLAVE=yes
MASTER=bond0.450
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
```

ifcfg-em2

```
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
DEVICE=em2
ONBOOT=yes
MASTER=bond0
NOZEROCONF=yes
ONBOOT=yes
SLAVE=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
NAME="System em2"
```

ifcfg-em2.341

```
DEVICE=em2.341
ONBOOT=yes
VLAN=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
SLAVE=yes
MASTER=bond0.341
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
```

ifcfg-em2.342

```
DEVICE=em2.342
ONBOOT=yes
VLAN=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
SLAVE=yes
MASTER=bond0.342
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
```

ifcfg-em2.400

```
DEVICE=em2.400
ONBOOT=yes
VLAN=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
SLAVE=yes
MASTER=bond0.400
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
```

ifcfg-em2.450

```
DEVICE=em2.450
ONBOOT=yes
VLAN=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
SLAVE=yes
MASTER=bond0.450
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
```

Comment: The vlan tagging occurs at the bond interface. All the tagging you are configuring for the bond slaves (em*) is unneeded / wrong. NM_CONTROLLED=no should be set as well.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! So I don't need them at all or just remove the vlan tagging?

Comment: You only need ifcfg-em1 and ifcfg-em2. All other ifcfg-em*.* should be removed

Comment: Also in this case you generally disable STP. VLAN=yes on the bridge interfaces is probably incorrect.

Comment: That did it! Thank you! I have one vlan not working, but I'm sure I can figure that out. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing my comments:

- vlan tagging occurs at the bond interface. ifcfg-em*.* should be removed
- NM_CONTROLLED=no should be set (don't want NM fouling things up)
- in this VM networking with bridges scenario STP is usually disabled
- VLAN=yes on the bridge interfaces is probably incorrect